# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead for K-fold cross validation

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, k-fold

I am trying to perform K-Fold Cross Validation for my dataset but an error message popped up instead

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

The data looks like this:

```
Fuel Consumption         Distance
13.046                   298.89
14.717                   468.60
15.032                   464.38
```

Below is the code that I have used:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=3,shuffle=True,random_state=42)
kf
```

```
x = data.loc[:,'Fuel Consumption'].values
y = data.loc[:, 'Distance'].values
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42, shuffle=True)
```

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(y):
    print(train_index, test_index)
```

```
def get_score(model, x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test):
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    return model.score(x_test, y_test)
```

```
scores = []
best_svr = SVR(kernel='rbf')
cv = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42, shuffle=True)

for train_index, test_index in cv.split(x):
    print("Train Index: ", train_index, "\n")
    print("Test Index: ", test_index)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = x[train_index], x[test_index], y[train_index], y[test_index]
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
best_svr.fit(x_train, y_train)
scores.append(best_svr.score(x_test, y_test))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @priscilla, you may want to strip your code to the absolutely necessary, i.e. create a [*minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Most of the functions won't affect the error, which is raised at a specific line...

Comment: You are reshaping `x_train` and `y_train` to be 2D arrays but you don't do this with `x_test` and `y_test` when calculating the `best_svr.score()`...

Comment: Hi Max, I have reshaped x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test but have an error message that looks like this DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected.